# Convergence of $\int_1^\infty\left[\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{-M}}\right)\right]^pdx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

So I have this integral:
$$
\int_1^\infty\left[\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{-M}}\right)\right]^pdx.
$$
The question is for what $M$ does the integral converge for a given $p > 0$.

So the problematic points are at $x=1$ and $x=\infty$, and I assumed that $M>0$ for every $p>0$.

My idea was to try and approximate the integrand in the limit with a polynomial and then procede from there to test for convergence.

So for $x\to\infty$ I got the following:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{-M}}\right)}{x^{\alpha}}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}{=}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{M\left(1-x^{-M}\right)x^{-M-1}}{\alpha x^{\alpha -1}}=\frac{M}{\alpha}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-x^{-M}\right)x^{-\alpha-M}
$$

so for the limit to be non-zero, $\alpha$ must be equal to $-M$ and therefore:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{-M}}\right) = \lim_{x\to\infty}x^{-M}.
$$

So now when I substitute $\ln(...)$ with $x^{-M}$, i get:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{-M}}\right)\right]^p=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{-Mp}
$$

and in order for it to converge, $-Mp$ must be smaller than $-1$. And from there for $M$:
$$
-Mp < -1 \Rightarrow M>{1\over p}.
$$
But when I want to do the same for $x\to 1$, I get stuck:
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{-M}}\right)}{(1-x)^{\alpha}}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}{=}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{M\left(1-x^{-M}\right)x^{-M-1}}{\alpha (1-x)^{\alpha -1}}=\;?
$$
So my questions are:

1. Is the first part for $x\to\infty$ correct and
2. How to solve the problem for $x\to1$

Comment: is  your constant $ M $ positive ?

Comment: I assumed that $M>0$, since for $M<0$ the logarithm is undefined and for $M=0$ it clearly diverges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first part is correct. I derived it differently, but I also came to the conclusion that $Mp > 1$.

To get the $x\to 1$ side, we can use a change of variables. Let $u = \log\left( \frac{1}{1-x^{-M}} \right)$. Then your integral becomes:

$$
\frac{1}{M}\int_0^\infty \frac{u^p e^{-u}}{\left(1-e^{-u}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{M}}}\,\mathrm{d}u
$$

The limit $x\to 1$ corresponds to $u\to\infty$ in this new integral. As $u\to\infty$ the denominator goes to $1$. More formally, for $u > \log(2)$, you have $\frac{1}{1-e^{-u}} < 2$ so you can upper-bound the tail of the integral by a constant times $\int_{\log{2}}^\infty u^p e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u$. This integral converges for all $p$, which shows the tail of the original integral converges for all $p$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I try to replicate your result i get that $du=(1-x^{-M})Mx^{-M-1}dx=e^{-u}M(1-e^{-u})^{1+{1\over M}}dx$, which then results in ${1\over M}\int_\infty^0{u^pe^u\over (1-e^{-u})^{1+{1\over M}}}$, which diverges for $u\to\infty$.

Comment: I think I did it correctly. The derivative of $\log( 1/(1-x^{-M}) )$ is $-M(1-x^{-M})^{-1}x^{-M-1}$. You forgot to apply the chain rule when differentiating the log.

Comment: Oh I see, I also made the same mistake in the question. Gonna mark your post as the answer.